# angular: matTable giving error "cannot read property 'find' of undefined" when compiling without --aot

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2, angular-material-6

The angular material table(matTable) is throwing the following error, when compile without --aot.

[image]

The application will working fine, if the target es version as **es5**. But the application is heavily depend on **es6** feature. So, should be compiled with es6 only.

Error can be reproduced using [**Github**](https://github.com/arshitabinda/reactore-repo) repository

**Updated**:

The material and cdk to is downgrade to 6.4.1 in package.json. But it installed the latest one. That cause the issue. If both the package installed separately. Then it is working. What could be issue..?

[image]

**Note:** *package-lock.json and node_modules where deleted before install npm.*

Answer (score 0):

I had that same problem, please check:

https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/11427

General: please check angular material version.